# Scheduling job every start of the day

Tags: scheduledexecutorservice

I am using `ScheduledExecutorService`, `scheduleAtFixedRate` method for running jobs every start of the day.

sample code is below,

```
Long midnight=LocalDateTime.now().until(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(), ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, midnight, 1440, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

but the job is running at "23:59:22" not at 00:00:00.
Can any one let me know what is wrong in code? how to run the job at the start of day?

Comment: probably system time is not in sync with scheduler.

Comment: i didn't get the comment, can you please explain me?